# How to rank the data set having multiple columns in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have data set like this which i am fetching from csv file but how to
store in Scala to do the processing.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| recent    | Freq      | Monitor  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|        1  |       1234|    199090|
|        4  |       2553|    198613|
|        6  |       3232 |   199090|
|        1  |       8823 |   498831|
|        7  |       2902 |   890000|
|        8  |       7991 |   081097|
|        9  |       7391 |   432370|
|        12 |       6138 |   864981|
|        7  |       6812 |   749821|
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Actually I need to sort the data and rank it.
I am new to Scala programming.
Thanks

Comment: what would be the rank? is there any formula?

Comment: I'd rank that data near the bottom.

Comment: @Niranjanp I don't understand what rank the data near the bottom means. Is there a formula to obtain the ranking? In the answer is clear what I am doing?

Comment: @jwh is making a comment about the clarity of your question,What do you mean by "rank"? Can you give an example of the data ordered by rank?

Comment: Actually I want the recent column value should be in ascending order and the remaining two are in the descending order and then i need to rank them.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question here is the solution, this code reads a csv and order by the third column

```
object CSVDemo extends App {
    println("recent, freq, monitor")
    val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("./data.csv")
    val list: Array[Array[String]] = (bufferedSource.getLines map { line => line.split(",").map(_.trim) }).toArray
    val newList = list.sortBy(_(2))
    newList map { line => println(line.mkString(" ")) }
    bufferedSource.close
}
```

you read the file and you parse it to an `Array[Array[String]]`, then you order by the third column, and you print

Comment: thanks this data set I am reading from csv file but how do i store in any collection type in scala like set or array.

Comment: @Niranjanp yesterday I didn't get the question, here is the solution. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciated it.

Comment: @Niranjanp you are welcome, if the answer is correct mark it, if not, please tell me and I try to fix it.

Comment: Now I am using this list and try to normalize each column

Comment: Sorry I am not able to format my code properly.  I will try to post it.

Comment: @Niranjanp, I am glad that helped, please create a new question for the new feature, someone else or me will try to answer, but keep this question/answer clean, and follow the rules of the site. That will help other members looking for answers.

Comment: My apologize for that. Actually my next question was related so that I asked. I will follow the rule Thanks

Comment: @ agusgambina sorry for again coming back to the same question I was wondering would it possible to sort each column independently in descending order.

Comment: @Niranjanp, sure it is, but please, accept in this question the correct answer and write a new question. To sort separately was not on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using the list and try to normalize each column at a time and then concatenating them. Is there any other way to iterate column wise and normalize them. Sorry my coding is very basic.

```
val col1 = newList.map(line => line.head)

val mi = newList.map(line => line.head).min

val ma = newList.map(line => line.head).max  

println("mininumn value of first column is " +mi)
println("maximum value of first column is : " +ma)

// calculate scale for the first column

val scale = col1.map(x => math.round((x.toInt - mi.toInt) / (ma.toInt - mi.toInt)))

println("Here is the normalized range of first column of the data") 

scale.foreach(println)
```

Comment: may i ask how this answer solves your question. i don't see any connection

Comment: My main task is to normalize the data and assign the rank.  From first code I loaded the CSV file and converted into the List(@gusgambina code). Secondly I am using that list and by iterating first element of each line  I found the minimum and maximum. Then used linear Min-Max normalization method to normalize it. Here I just put code for only one column from list. Similarly I am doing for rest columns and then try to merge them.  Is this the correct way of doing this.

Comment: is this a new question ??? if so please post it as a new question ! and if the answer provided for this one answers your first question please accept it to close the issue

Comment: than accept then answer to the question and ask a new one ! and seriously read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) !